# Link with hidden Id

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I'm using Java, SpringMVC, Hibernate and MySql.

I have a question. In database i have user entity. Some User have role Admin.
If user have role Admin, can create project travel like "Go to Africa" and can join another people.

When User with admin Role login to system, in first site he see projects created by him. He can click on  any project. For examle "Go to africa". Then he join friend to list. 
But.
Link to a specific project look like:

```
   <a href="managementProject?idProject=${id_project}">ProjectXX</a>
```

and in controller i have `@RequestParam("idProject")`

But it is really stupid solution because URL look like:
`localhost:2233/managementProject?idSchool=5`

If i change idSchool param in URL, i have access to someone projects. 
I dont no how send this value Post method (because this is element , not form)

So I wrote a method that checks if `idProject` agree with project created by a person logged on:

```
private boolean checkAuth(int idProject,User user){
            List<Project> projectList = new ArrayList<Project>(user.getProjectsAdministrators());

            for(Project project:projectList){
                if (project.getId_project()==idProject){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
    }
```

If true, user can add people to project. If false, modelAndView return 403 page (something like "you do not have permission"
But i don't no it is really good solution. Maybe someone have better?
Sorry for my english.

Thanks!

Comment: I do not understand the problem, server-side security checks are a must. In case you want to post the request just use an HTML form - you still have to perform server-side security checks...

Comment: To use a form and a POST, add a Javascript handler to each anchor,  which save the form ID in a hidden input, then submits the form. The server-side security is still a must.

Comment: If you want `idProject` value not to be plain text in the url, you can encode its value (Base64) and decode it on server side. But, this would be just cosmetic fix, anyone could still decode if if they would want to.

Comment: @home problem is when i change id in url because then i have access to someone project. Not mine. Okay, another problem that looks like problem from my post.

When i have list user in project i can delete some people.
<a href="/delete?id=${idPeople}>DELETE</a>

Its not good solution because if i write in url sometime like:
localhost:2233/managementProjct/delete?id=5 or 6 or 7 
i can delete another people. I want have access only for mine project.

Comment: @Lukas: This is exactly what I mean - you must perform security validation on the server-side for each and every request (HTTP protocol does not support data security checks). HTTP Post will just hide the parameters as they are not shown in the browser URL, but an attacker can still use tools like curl to access restricted data.

Comment: @home Okay, so if my method of checking idProject taken from the url belongs to the list projects created by the person logged on is a good solution? Sorry for stupid question but i'm young programmer

Comment: @Lukas: this is not a stupid question? Just make sure that each and every endpoint (spring controller) performs the required security checks.

Comment: @home ok thank u for your help! Do you have some tutorial about how   cheks required security ? I have only about login panel etc but not about what you say.